# How does node.js http.get() "on(end,callback())" event works?

Tags: javascript, node.js

My question is: How does the "http.get()", on.("end",callback) event work?

What is the hierarchy of the code execution?

I'm asking because I have this code

```
var http = require("http")
var str = ""

http.get(process.argv[2],function(res){
    res.setEncoding("utf8")
    res.on("data",function(data){
        str+= data

    })

    res.on("end",function(){
        console.log(str.length)
        console.log(str)


    })

})
```

is the `on.end` part would print me the str.length every time its called?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To start with,

- **function(res)** is called when the connection is established.
- **on('data')** is called when there's a chunk of data (this almost certainly will be more than once)
- **on('end')** is called when the connection closes.
- **on('error')** is called when there is some sort of error.

This code means that till the data is incoming (in chunks), the response will be appended every time it is received from `data` to `str` and when the receiving has ended it will console `str.length` and `str`.

You can read this for better understanding: [colmsjo.com/130721_Streams_in_NodeJS](http://colmsjo.com/130721_Streams_in_NodeJS)